# Question about QGIS Server installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual box with Win 7 (64 bit) being the host & I'm a newbie to Linux environment.

I am installing QGIS Server on Ubuntu following this [**tutorial**](http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/) in which I was able to add successfully to "`/etc/apt/sources.list`"

In next step we need to add key and update the package list which I'm unable to find a key for Ubuntu and QGIS Server.

- Tried searching on Google and confused as to where should I obtain the key from?
- In QGIS Server official version they have provided key but its not working for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any help regarding this will be great!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy,

Surely after running `sudo apt-get update` you've got an error telling you you lack the public key for the QGIS repository. For installing the appropriate key take note of the last 8 characters of the missing key and use them in the following two commands, instead DD45F6C3.

I've just installed QGIS this morning (2014 Dec. 15th) and DD45F6C3 was the key I was missing.

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

After this, you can successfuly do `sudo apt-get update` and install QGIS.